# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in loop

Tags: r, loops

```
> dput(data1)
structure(list(x = c(35.829875, 35.64903952, 35.87826747, 35.83962222, 
35.94296667, 35.94184918, 35.87022926, 35.84118463, 35.84861677, 
35.86461772), y = c(128.550225, 128.4373915, 128.6094381, 128.5711917, 
128.5503917, 128.5629876, 128.6917042, 128.610549, 128.6244008, 
128.595875), a = c(116.0591995, 59.11426175, 255.8600501, 190.7975442, 
196.714572, 412.3129316, 267.8455805, 459.7797184, 131.1416782, 
380.2493612), b = c(411.7159889, 438.7649907, 54.60376166, 339.2778169, 
321.3185479, 319.6080094, 476.1722991, 372.3019021, 205.9843768, 
184.6394583)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

> listname
[1] "data1" "data2" "data3" "data4" "data5"

> check_list<-list()
> for (i in listname) {
+  for (j in listname) {
+   check <- table(i["x"] == j["x"])
+   check_list[[paste0(i,"_",j)]] <- check
+  }
+ }

> check_list
$data1_data1
< table of extent 0 >
```

> listname[1]$x
>   Error in listname[1]$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I wrote a loop statement that compares the x variables of multiple data frames. But the same result was shown.
So I ran the code alone. Then I found that this error occurred.
What can I do to solve this error?

+Example data was added. There are a total of 5 data such as data1.

Comment: What is `data1`, `data2`... ? Please share your data using `dput` also read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @Ronak Shah Oh sorry. I didn't consider it. Please check the post has been modified.

Comment: please use dput, do not copy paste the console log output.

Comment: Are all `data1`, `data2`....`data5` of same dimensions? (column and rows). How would your expected output look like ?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah All data is the same row and column. I just want to make sure that the values ​​of the x variables in each data are all the same. Like TRUE or FLASE

Answer (score 0):

Get all the data in the list and extract the `"x"` column from each dataframe and using `outer` check if `all` the values are the same which will return you `TRUE`/`FALSE` value.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0("data", 1:5))
all_xs <- lapply(list_df, `[[`, 'x')

compare_fun <- function(x, y) all(x == y)

outer(all_xs, all_xs, Vectorize(compare_fun))
```